# Keep getting an error when trying php artisan migrate:fresh --seed and php artisan db:seed

Tags: laravel

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
    Dropped all tables successfully.
    Migration table created successfully.
    Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
    Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (388.12ms)
    Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
    Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (664.45ms)
    Migrating: 2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table
    Migrated:  2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table (125.81ms)
    Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
    Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (456.85ms)
    Migrating: 2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table
    Migrated:  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table (1,087.48ms)
    Migrating: 2021_06_07_082644_create_sessions_table
    Migrated:  2021_06_07_082644_create_sessions_table (2,139.29ms)
    
       Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 
    
      Target class [Database\Seeders\UsersTableSeeder] does not exist.
    
      at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879
        875▕
        876▕         try {
        877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    
      1   D:\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
          ReflectionException::("Class "Database\Seeders\UsersTableSeeder" does not exist")
    
      2   D:\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
    -kelompok-7\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:40
          Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()

UserTableSeeder.php

<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        User::factory()->create([
            'name'      =>  'Admin',
            'email'     =>  'admin@example.com',
            'password'  =>  bcrypt('password');
            'type'      =>  User::ADMIN,
        ]);

        User::factory()->count(5)->create();
    }
}
```

What should i do to fix Class "Database\Seeders\User" not found ? I already triedmigrate fresh and db:seed but its not working. how can i make the User working? I need some help. I need to make it long because i keep getting an "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: You have a typo. Your seeder class is named `UserTableSeeder` and the error is telling you `UsersTableSeeder` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error because There's no Class called 'UsersTableSeeder' , and The Class Name is 'UserTableSeeder' - without 'S' .
so check the DatabaseSeeder.php in Database\Seeders and modify it and run the command again , it will work .

Answer (score 0):

In the DatabaseSeeder.php change what you have in the `run()` from

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UsersTableSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
```

to

```
public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UserTableSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to import this.

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Hope This will work.